# How to refer to cell without A1 notation?

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

In my Access VBA I have hyperlink, which is using the following way to link to cell:

```
oSheet.Cells(1, i).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""#Sheet2!E6"", """ & !TestCase & """)"
```

However, instead of E6, I want to use `row,col` notation, since all my internal application logic is using Cells/rows/cols.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Formula`use `FormulaR1C1`(Row / Column format)

Here are two examples:

*Set the formula of your cells to `=$B$1` :*

```
oSheet.Cells(1, i).FormulaR1C1 = "=R1C2"
```

*Set the formula of A1 to `=C2`, A2 to `=C3` etc.:*

```
Range("A1:A10").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[1]C[2]"
```